# What drives religious belief?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I am fascinated by the way the human brain deals with infinity and other trivia. What is it that distinguishes our belief systems, rational vs. irrational? It is certainly not intelligence. Is that a paradox?

Comment: Saving faith is a gift from God, so you can think of it as God's way of making Himself known to believers in a more personal way. It's only possible to know true faith as a result of repentance. Psychologically, I believe it's kind of like having a more acute sense of God's excellence. In that way, it might be thought of as being somewhat similar to moral sense, i.e. how we naturally recognize the difference between good and bad. However, it's also accompanied by a deeper certainty of God's existence as well.

Comment: It's certainly not intelligence?

Comment: And infinity is a trivia?

Comment: Haidt, a well-known social psychologist, gives an interesting take in the blog post [Moral Psychology and the Misunderstanding of Religion](https://www.edge.org/conversation/jonathan_haidt-moral-psychology-and-the-misunderstanding-of-religion), countering the oversimplifications of "new atheism":"*There must be some combination of evolutionary, developmental, neuropsychological, and anthropological theories that can explain why human religious practices take the various forms that they do, many of which are so similar across cultures and eras.*"

Comment: It's counterintuitive to think that those who have no faith understand anything about it. For that reason, you'll find much more reliable information from a good theologian than from any secular source. I recommend Herman Bavinck, who addressed this question with a remarkable amount of depth.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is infinity trivial? A belief system may be rational or irrational, intelligent or stupid, Where's the paradox? Why is the question interesting in religion or science? I'd suggest some editing.

Comment: I can't immediately see the connection between your question and your gloss on it. What 'drives' religious belief is presumably a psychological matter. What if anything distinguishes rational from irrational belief systems is a matter of conceptual analysis - at least so far as concerns this forum.

Comment: The first sentence was very much tongue in cheek, apologies. Rationality is surely psychological by nature and not absolute. Beliefs that were entirely rational in an earlier world can now be fairly considered irrational as a result of improved knowledge. However the brain’s wiring is subject to evolution and some minds are clearly more able to deny current rationality than others.

Comment: Is there an assumption here that religious belief is irrational? That would be a tough result to prove, even though many such beliefs are demonstrably so.

Comment: As others have commented, the title and the content of the question appear unrelated. I have no idea what is actually being asked.

Answer (score 4):

My reading of Justin Barrett’s “Born Believers: the science of children’s religious belief” suggest that a propensity for religious belief is beyond culture, intelligence or rationality.  It is innate.  This does not mean that a particular religion’s dogmas are innate.  A particular religion attempts to mold culturally this propensity to believe which is already in the child.

Also consider Jonathan Haidt’s “The Righteous Mind”.  He discusses his, also innate, moral foundations one of which deals with the sacred.  Haidt’s intuitionism may resolve the “rational vs irrational” part of the question by saying it is neither since most of us aggressively rationalize our snap decisions.  Sometimes these prior decisions are modified by our motivated attempts to justify them, but the main job of our reasoning ability is to justify, not falsify, those commitments.  See his lecture, “[The Rationalist Delusion in Moral Psychology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kI1wQswRVaU&t=536s)” , for a quick summary of his ideas.

I don’t see this situation as “paradoxical”.  It is just the way things are given those two theories and the evidence collected to justify them, but I can see it might be unintelligible or meaningless to some other perspectives.

Comment: The first sentence was very much tongue in cheek, apologies. Rationality is surely psychological by nature and not absolute. Beliefs that were entirely rational in an earlier world can now be fairly considered irrational as a result of improved knowledge. However the brain’s wiring is subject to evolution and some minds are clearly more able to deny current rationality than others.

Comment: @adlibber I agree that rationality is not absolute although I probably would not had I not read Haidt's book.  The metaphor "wiring" for the brain, given that it changes, may not be best, but I can't think of any replacement for it at the moment.  The metaphor does suggest that the brain constrains us in multiple ways.  I would like a metaphor that is not so deterministic.

Comment: Being an old engineer, I consider 'wiring' to represent a flexible connection not a permanent one, Frank. Completely agree that my metaphor shouldn't be deterministic! Anyone interested in neural science would support that view. In fact the word 'plastic' is now frequently used in respect of some of the brain's connections.